# How to deal with few trends in my time series?

Tags: time-series, python, trend

I would like to make this data stationary, but I do not know how to deal with this series. This is not stationary and has autocorrelation. It looks like it has 3 different trends. How should I treat this data? Should I consider 3 different trends and separetely with this data? Or this is not right method?

[image]

Comment: You need to tell us some context for this to be answerable!  What does your series represent? Daily observations? Some external shocks? What is your goal? ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I only got the data and I don't know anything about them, and the names of the variables don't tell me anything. These are observations from January 2020 to May 2020, taken every minute. My goal is to figure out how to deal with this data to make them stationary

Comment: Please add this new info to the post as an edit .